# Не хотели бы вы стать участником видеочата о разработке проектов с открытым исходным кодом?

Tags: обсуждение, видеочат

[Дмитрий Полянин](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/205037/?tab=profile) и [я](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/6/?tab=profile) планируем организовать [видеочат](/questions/tagged/%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%82) на тему «Разработка проектов с открытым исходным кодом» в обозримом будущем и хотим пригласить еще одного человека стать участником выпуска.

Если вы хотите поделиться с коллегами своим опытом разработки проектов с открытым исходным кодом и мыслями на этот счет, пожалуйста, напишите мне на почту о своем желании: nicolas.chabanovsky@stackoverflow.com Я свяжусь с вами, и мы обговорим удобное для вас время и интересующие вас темы беседы.

Давайте рассказывать о себе, своих интересах и делиться своим жизненным опытом в видеоформате!

Comment: Отлично! Тогда ждём когда появится второй участник!

Comment: Написал Николасу (мой ОС проект у меня в инфо указан, хостится на гитхабе). Вдруг будет интересно.

Comment: @Kromster круто! Мне было бы интересно с тобой участвовать в видеочате.

Comment: @Kromster, я [там](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/177188/kromster) вроде только игры вижу... Не там смотрю?

Comment: @avp верно, и 2 из 3 это "проекты с открытым исходным кодом", хостятся на гитхабе. Что вас смущает?

Comment: @Kromster, слово **ОС** в вашем комментарии (теперь я понял, что это надо понимать `"Опен Сорс"`, а не `"Операционная Система"`)