# Выпуск видеочата №8 с @Дмитрий Полянин и @Kromster 15.08.2019 в 17:49. Присоединяйтесь!

Tags: обсуждение, видеочат

С радостью приглашаю всех участников сообщества присоединиться к видеочату в четверг 15-го августа 2019 года в 17:49 по московскому времени. Гостями восьмого выпуска будут

- [@Дмитрий Полянин](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/205037/tab=profile). Дмитрий закончил Мех-Мат МГУ им М.В. Ломоносова, а затем аспирантуру МГУИЭ. Начал работу с .NET с 1.0-beta2, которая появилась 17 лет назад. Вел авторский курс по AspNet MVC в GeekBrains. На работе использует C#, Java, C++, C, perl, php, JavaScript. В свободное время любит фотографировать природу.
- [@Kromster](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/177188/kromster). Даниил по образованию графический дизайнер. Переквалифицировался в программисты через неделю после защиты диплома. Путь в программирование начал написания инструментов для моддинга игр. Свои игры пишет с 2008 года. Сделал ремейк стратегии «Война и Мир» под названием «KaM Remake». Все на Delphi. На работе использует Delphi / JavaScript.

Тема этого выпуска — [проекты с открытым кодом](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/9345/6). Проекты ребят:

- [sunengine.site](https://github.com/Dmitrij-Polyanin/SunEngine)
- [kamremake.com](https://github.com/Kromster80/kam_remake)

Запись видео доступна на канале сообщества: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GsqG2z_FNAk.

#### Пожалуйста, задавайте ваши вопросы!

Главная цель видеочата – узнать друг друга поближе. Расскажите, что бы вам хотелось узнать о разработке ПО с открытым исходным кодом и опыте участников выпуска! Пожалуйста, задавайте ваши вопросы Дмитрию и Даниилу!

Вопросы вы можете задать в [чате сообщества](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22462/stack-overflow--). Обязательно, задавая вопрос, упомяните `@NicolasChabanovsky`, чтобы я мог своевременно отреагировать на вопрос. Также вы можете отправить ваш вопрос заранее мне на почту (nicolas.chabanovsky@stackoverflow.com) или опубликовать комментарием или ответом на данный вопрос.

С нетерпением ждем вас 15-го августа в 17:49!

Comment: А как посмотреть ???

Comment: @timob256 Ссылка на YouTube-трансляцию должна будет появиться в этом вопросе на месте слов "(ссылка появится позже)", но, очевидно, опазывают с трансляцией почему-то.

Comment: Трансляция задерживается, пытаемся настроить захват звука.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov Вадим как думаешь насколько опоздают ??? (А то я не дома и мне сложно оставаться "тут" )

Comment: @Kromster так через сколько приблизительно будет ??

Comment: @timob256 Вообще без понятия, я к ней отношения не имею. Видимо, придётся смотреть в записи, у меня тоже со временем не очень.

Comment: Мои вопросы не задали :( (я немго напрямую в ютубе написать ибо я не дома )

Comment: @timob256 ответил в чате. Если что-то еще будет интересно - спрашивайте )

Comment: Спасибо! Было очень круто!